# Ember model mapping with Server response

Tags: ember.js, asp.net-web-api

I am using asp.net web api for getting JSON response.

```
public class Artist
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }

    }
```

and my ember model looks like this

```
Music.Artist = DS.Model.extend({
    name:DS.attr('string'),
    age:DS.attr('number')
});
```

It is not mapping due to its case. When i make my model at the server side 'name' instead of 'Name' it works. Do i need to take care of casing also, or there is some method.

Another thing, it always require id, what if i have id by another name, eg. artist_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override both how ember-data process the attribute key and the id.

To change the attribute key override the [keyForAttribute](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#method_keyForAttribute) method, the `attr` is your model attribute, and the return is the related key coming from the json. Because you want to process "name" as "Name", `Ember.String.capitalize` will do the work.

To change the id, just override the [primaryKey](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#property_primaryKey) property.

Below is the custom serializer

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
  primaryKey: 'Id',
  keyForAttribute: function(attr) { 
    return Ember.String.capitalize(attr);
  }
});
```

A live sample with this code can be found in http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/950/edit